# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

can anyone help me debug this error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl required a 
bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao' in your configuration.
```

Below are my files:

**UserController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import com.example.demo.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;
    
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return userService.getUserById(userId);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Long addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.addUser(user);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{userId}")
    public void updateUser(@PathVariable Long userId, @RequestBody User user) {
        user.setUserId(userId);
        userService.updateUser(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
    }
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {
    User getUserById(Long userId);

    List<User> getAllUsers();

    Long addUser(User user);

    void updateUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(Long userId);
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.demo.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    private final UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Long userId) {
        return userDao.getUserById(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public Long addUser(User user) {
        return userDao.addUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userDao.updateUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long userId) {
        userDao.deleteUser(userId);
    }
}
```

**UserDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public UserDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Long userId) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userId}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(User.class));
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(User.class));
    }

    @Override
    public Long addUser(User user) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, email, user_avatar_url, podcast_id) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getEmail(),
                user.getUserAvatarUrl(), user.getPodcastId());

        // Retrieve the auto-generated user_id
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", Long.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        String sql = "UPDATE user SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, email = ?, " +
                "user_avatar_url = ?, podcast_id = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getEmail(),
                user.getUserAvatarUrl(), user.getPodcastId(), user.getUserId());
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long userId) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, userId);
    }
}
```

**UserDao.java**

```
package com.example.demo.dao;
import com.example.demo.model.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserDao {
    User getUserById(Long userId);

    List<User> getAllUsers();

    Long addUser(User user);

    void updateUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(Long userId);
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan("com.example.demo.service")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have tried `@ComponentScan("com.example.demo.service")` in the DemoApplication.java but it doesn't work.

I've also tried putting @Autowire and mark the service with @Service. Also I've checked all other annotations and i don't see anything else that's missing

I expect a clean build and access to the apis

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKYyF.png)

Comment: I don't see an implementation of `UserService`. If there is none, create an implementation and add `@Service` on top of that class, you can remove the same from the interface.

Comment: The UserService is used in the UserController

Comment: The second file is an interface, not an implementation.

Comment: @DMR that's an interface, please check again

Comment: Ok, so you're saying to convert the interface to a class and mark it as @Service?

Comment: Ok I've added a UserServiceImpl and removed the @Service from the interface. But still not working. Please see my latest edits in the original post

Comment: Now i get an error that says 'Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.'

Comment: the code that you shared is working as expected i tested your getbyid and getallusers, hence i think it might be a caching issue

Comment: How do you recommend I get around the caching issue. I did a maven clean install but still same issue

Comment: Did you configure a database like H2 or some external one? No datasource setup not `JdbcTemplate` no `UserDaoImpl` and then you will get the error mentioned.

Comment: Datasource properties are set in the application.properties

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an implementation of `UserService`. If you wanted to keep your current implementation of `@Repository` (`UserDao`), then you could rewrite your service as following:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    // implement using your DAO
    User getUserById(Long userId);
    List<User> getAllUsers();
    Long addUser(User user);
    void updateUser(User user);
    void deleteUser(Long userId);
}
```

That should make it available to `UserController` then.

**EDIT:**

After your updates, it seems that your `UserDaoImpl` can't be automatically injected now, since it is missing `@Autowired`:

```java
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public UserDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: I've removed the @Service from the user service interface and i added the UserServiceImpl but still not working. See my edits now above

Comment: Now it's complaining that it cannot find com.example.demo.dao.UserDao

Comment: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.

Comment: I have updated the response now. It seems that your `UserDaoImpl` was missing `@Autowired` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a UserService implementation and Spring can't find it as a bean. You have a couple of options:

1. Provide an implementation of your UserService interface, put the `@Service("UserService")` annotation on the implementation class, and remove the annotation from the interface.
2. Change the interface to a concrete class and implement the methods.

There are additional ways, such as abstract classes, but they tend to be uncommon.

Comment: I've done that but now it says `Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.`

Comment: You shouldn't be passing a DAO to the serviceImpl constructor. You pass the DAO to the service methods.